# What quantities in Schwarzchild spacetime correspond to those we measure?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, event-horizon, observables

There are many classical tests of general relativity such as gravitational red shift, motion of particles, etc. In those calculations, we compare the result under general relativity with that under classical mechanics. Since coordinates on the manifold are actually quite abstrast, how to correspond quantities in Schwarzschild spacetime with classical ones seems difficult to me.

For example, in the model of Shapiro time delay, does proper time $\Delta \tau$ or coordinate time $\Delta t$ correspond to the time delay we can measure? In the paper *Fourth Test of General Relativity*, what it calculates is proper time, while in the book *General Relativity* by Norbert Straumann, it calculates coordinate time. So I'm confused which one is  measured by us. Besides, $\Delta t$ and $\Delta \tau$ are expressed in terms of $r$, so is it to say Schwarzschild coordinate radius $r$ corresponds to the one we measure?

Is my conjecture true, and why do these quantities correspond to classical ones?

Comment: Your clock measures your proper time, which is time in your coordinate system. Distance is neither uniquely defined in GR nor can be measured directly. Before your question can be answered, you need to clarify what exactly you measure and how exactly you measure it. Your observations don’t necessarily match values expressed in your coordinates.  You also need to clarify what exactly you mean by “corresponds”.  A better approach is to think in terms of measurable predictions.